Error: <spyOnProperty> : href is not declared configurable
I am new to angular test case writing.
This is my .ts file

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'dp-se-login',
      templateUrl: './se-login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./se-login.component.scss']
    })
    export class SeLoginComponent implements OnInit {
      public pingSAMLreqURL = "/saml2/authenticate/uat-sei-idp";
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.pingSAMLreqURL = `${environment.samlURL}`;
      }
      onSamlLoginClick() {
        window.location.href = this.pingSAMLreqURL;
      }
    }


and this is how i have written the .spec.ts of the same

    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
    import { SeLoginComponent } from './se-login.component';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    
    describe('SeLoginComponent', () => {
    
      let component: SeLoginComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<SeLoginComponent>;
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [SeLoginComponent],
          imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()]
        }).compileComponents();
      });
      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SeLoginComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
      it('should create the component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
      it('should initialize pingSAMLreqURL with environment value', () => {
        expect(component.pingSAMLreqURL).toEqual(environment.samlURL);
      });
    
      it('should redirect to SAML login URL when onSamlLoginClick is called', () => {
        const spy = spyOnProperty(window.location, 'href', 'set').and.returnValue(undefined);
        component.onSamlLoginClick();
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(environment.samlURL);
      });
    });


I am getting the issue when I run the ng test coverage command and there over I can see the line has not been covered:

Along with that I am having these error:
Please help me so that the lines can be covere
d

Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Windows 10) SeLoginComponent should redirect to SAML login URL when onSamlLoginClick is called FAILED
        Error: <spyOnProperty> : href is not declared configurable
        Usage: spyOnProperty(<object>, <propName>, [accessType])
            at <Jasmine>
            at UserContext.apply (src/app/core/components/login/se-login/se-login.component.spec.ts:29:17)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:368:26)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:273:39)

